# find maximum value of a column in a nested list using a purrr:::map function

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a list which is structured like this:

```
      examplelist<- lst(n1=tibble(Day= 1:10, text=letters[1:10]),
                      n2=tibble(Day= 11:20, text=letters[1:10]))
```

I want to perform operations recursively on each column in each tibble. For example I want to create a vector which includes the maximum value in each Day column. I want to use one of the map() functions.

I have tried

```
examplelist %>% map_depth(1, "Day", max)
and
map(examplelist,~.[["Day"]],max)
```

However these just return all the values in the Day column

$n1
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$n2
[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

when the answer should be 10 and 20 respectively

I'd really appreciate help to find a solution using a map() function. I'd appreciate a description of how the solution works because i'm new to R. I need it to be generalisable as there are other functions i might want to apply in future.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your

```
map(examplelist,~.[["Day"]],max)
```

is not working is because the function `~.[["Day"]]` is just that, returning the vector. Your `max` is being passed within `...`, but since the `~`-function is ignoring it, nothing changes.

You can wrap `max` around your extraction, ala

```r
map(examplelist,~max(.[["Day"]]))
# $n1
# [1] 10
# $n2
# [1] 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
library(tidyverse)

examplelist %>%
  map(.x = .,
      .f = ~.x %>%
        pull(Day) %>%
        max())

$n1
[1] 10

$n2
[1] 20
```